# Svg correct format template for the latest vesion of xml & svg in 2019/2020

Tags: xml, templates, svg, syntax

While copying the basic template for an svg animation from this tutorial:

[SVG Line Animation Tutorial with CSS & Other Fun Stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBdbgD2BaEI)

to make an animated svg hamburger menu, I noticed that neither of the
xmlns="" or xmlns:xlink="" attributes where utilizing https protocol,
so I prepended an s to the http link and copied it into the browser to see if these
would infact be valid links & therefore be ok to use in my template.

[image: Svg template from youtube tutorial]
https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd

is a valid link, but it is still not using the most recent version of svg version="2.0"
if there is a newer version still above this then please leave a comment with docs.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-SVG12-20030429/

takes me to an outdated article,
which refers me to this newer version here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG12/
even the examples in the docs for SVG2;

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#NewDocument
are still using svg version="1.1"?[image: W3C SVG 2 documentation]

Above is a screen shot from the W3C SVG version 2 Specification. Which you can clearly see is still using XML version 1.0 & SVG version 1.1.

the xmlns:xlink url was Last modified: $Date: 2000/06/22 15:15:22
Which is nearly 10 years ago at the end of the month.
I know that there is version 1.1 xml but this is only useful if you are
using some obscure languages with weird symbols.

Does anyone know the updated Urls for https SVG version 2.0 or higher if there is any?

Who-ever marked these as a duplicate the first one you linked to is over 6 years Old & the Second one is over three years Old, So these are not relevant to my Question.

Comment: The namepsace for SVG 2 is the same as for SVG 1.1

Comment: you've closed the question without fully providing any answer or feedback, whats the URI's to use for version 2.0 svg?

Comment: I provided a comment with that information. And it's not a URI, it's a namespace. It simply looks like a URI, like a hoverfly looks like a wasp without actually being a wasp.

Comment: even the same in the doctype?

Comment: There is no doctype for SVG 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Why do you think they've used examples of SVG 1.1 in the SVG 2.0 Specification. Seems a bit counter-intuitive....

Comment: SVG1.1 and SVG 2 overlap. You could always ask w3c via https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/

Comment: Arrgh cool, thanks for the reference. Will be useful.

Comment: @Robert Longson The Questions you linked to Are Over 6 years Old & are not relevant to this specific question.

Comment: @Robert Longson Well it does as Standards change & languages & Syntax change aswell..

Comment: But not in this case. If you don't think the links explain the question, edit the question to explain clearly what is not covered.